# dotnet publish with absolute path do not respect output

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, publish, git-bash

**Repro**

On windows with git bash:

I created some asp net core web app with razor pages. Now I would like to publish it to directory.

```
dotnet publish -o C:\temp\myApp
```

Temp directory exists, wheras MyApp not exists yet.

**Problem**

dotnet publish to ..\currentProjectDirectory\tempmyApp

Why its happens? I have also tried to run git bash with admin permissions, but it has not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use git bash. It means you should use `linux-style` path:

```
dotnet publish -o /c/temp/myApp
```